# Download Blob file in Rails App is shown inline and not attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blob

I get a blob from a function in my oracle Datenbank. Users of my Rails App should be able to download these BLOB. My Problem is, that after clicking on download, the BLOB file is shown inline in the browser, but it should be download as a file.

link:

```
= link_to export_pldw_plausibility_path, :class => "btn btn-primary 
    action-button" do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
    %span.hidden-xs
= "Export"
```

route:

```
resources :pldw_plausibilities do
  get 'export', on: :member
end
```

controller:

```
def export
  send_data PldwPlausibility.export(params[:id]), :filename => "test.BLOB", 
   :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

Model:

```
def self.export(id)
  return plsql.pld.pld_mdc.exportMDOC('PLD_PLAUSIBILITY', id.to_i)
end
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHUgR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry!

Adding `:target => "_blank"` to the link solves this Problem..